# Banachewicz identity

Tags: linear-algebra

Please, help solve this question:

I need to factorize/simplify this matrix, a.k.a. Banachewicz identity:

Given the partitioned matrix \begin{equation} P=\left( \begin{array} {c,c} A \quad B \\ C \quad D \end{array} \right) \end{equation} where $A$ and $D$ are nonsingular. Then by  Banachewicz identity,\begin{equation} P^{-1}=\left( \begin{array} {c,c} A^{-1}+A^{-1}B(D-CA^{-1}B)^{-1} \quad -A^{-1}B(D-CA^{-1}B)^{-1} \\ -(D-CA^{-1}B)^{-1}CA^{-1} \quad (D-CA^{-1}B)^{-1} \end{array} \right) \end{equation}
Now, can I write
\begin{equation} P^{-1}=(D-CA^{-1}B)^{-1}\left( \begin{array} {c,c} (D-CA^{-1}B)A^{-1}+A^{-1}B \quad -A^{-1}B \\ -CA^{-1} \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad I \end{array} \right) \end{equation}
Actually, my concern is the dimension of the matrices:\begin{equation}\end{equation} $A$ is $pxp$, $B$ is $pxq$, $C$ is $qxp$ and $D$ is $qxq$. With this dimension, \begin{equation}(D-CA^{-1}B)A^{-1} \end{equation} is not valid. What do I do?